# How to elegantly "min" and then perform an operation with the reference in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, functional-programming

Suppose you have two lists `nums1` and `nums2`, and you want to check which of the two lists first elements is smaller, remove it and then move that into an accumulator list which you return.

You might accomplish it using the following code:

```
def stackoverflowmethod(nums1, nums2):
    accumulator = [] 
    # determine if nums1[0] or nums2[0] is smaller and then remove it
    if nums1[0] <= nums2[0]:
        accumulator.append(nums1.pop(0))
    else:
        accumulator.append(nums2.pop(0))
    return accumulator
```

However this might look very unsightly in that you would rather have written something like

```
def idealMethod(nums1, nums2):
    accumulator.append(RemoveFromTheFrontOfOYourList(min(nums1[0], nums2[0])))
    return accumulator
```

The only thing that makes this hard is the mysterious method `RemoveFromTheFrontOfOYourList` needs to be able to figure out which list an item came from after the `min` operation was conducted on it,

I.E. if we had a slightly less forgetful `min` function then something elegant could be done here.

If stylistically what I'm asking for makes sense, how does one accomplish it in python 3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `min` *on the lists*, with `operator.itemgetter(0)` as the key function.

```
import operator

smaller_0 = min(nums1, nums2, key=operator.itemgetter(0))
accumulator.append(smaller_0.pop(0))
```

`operator.itemgetter(0)` is the same as `lambda x: x[0]` for this purpose.

---

Or use a ternary that gets the list with a smaller item 0, then pop from it

```
smaller_0 = nums1 if nums1[0] <= nums2[0] else nums2
accumulator.append(smaller_0.pop(0))
```

*This is like [Michael's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59904634/4518341), but a bit [DRYer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)*

Comment: This one's nice because you can extend it to work with any number of lists: `smallest = min(*list_of_nums, key=operator.itemgetter(0))`

Answer (score 2):

Use a ternary statement:

```py
acc.append(nums1.pop(0)) if nums1[0] < nums2[0] else acc.append(nums2.pop(0))
```

Comment: I think factoring out the `acc.append` could make this even nicer: `acc.append(nums1.pop(0) if nums1[0] < nums2[0] else nums2.pop(0))`

Comment: @Brian You could even factor out the `.pop(0)`: `acc.append((nums1 if nums1[0] < nums2[0] else nums2).pop(0))`, though it's clearer to write it in two lines like I put in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59904696/4518341).